# Ajuda em uma máscara JavaScript para um formulário

Tags: javascript, html

Um dos campos do formulário requer a seguinte validação:

Deve conter 6 números, sendo o que último, deve ser o resultado da soma dos demais. Caso essa soma seja maior que 10, deve-se somar todos os algarismos do resultado até que o novo resultado atenda esse requisito. Caso a soma seja 10, o valor considerado para o sexto número do "Número de registro" é 0.

HTML:

```
Número de Registro:<br >< input type="text" name="registro" onblur="validaRegistro(this.value)">< div id="m3">< /div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function validaRegistro(value) {
  var padrao = /^[0-9]+$/;
  if (value.match(padrao)){
    document.getElementById("m3").innerHTML="<font color='green'>Ok!</font>";
  } 
  else {
    document.getElementById("m3").innerHTML="<font color='red'>Campo incorreto</font>";
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que descreveu na pergunta, o código abaixo irá atendê-lo (veja os comentários):

```js
function validaRegistro(value){
   var padrao = /^\d{6}$/; // só aceita 6 dígitos à partir do início
   var valida = true; // flag para validar a soma
   if(value.match(padrao)){
      var nums = value.split('').map(Number); // crio uma array com os números
      var ultimo = nums.pop(); // pego e retiro o último número da array
      var soma = 0; // valor inicial da soma
      for(var vals of nums){ // loop para somar os 5 dígitos da array
         soma += vals;
      }

      if(soma > 10){
         valida = false; // se a soma for maior que 10, invalida
      }else if(soma == 10){
         var resultado = nums.join('')+"0"; // se for igual a 10, junto a array e concateno 0
      }else{
         var resultado = nums.join('')+ultimo; // se for menor que 10, junto a array e concateno com o último dígito
      }
   }else{
      valida = false; // não atendeu ao regex
   }

   if(valida){ // se os requisitos foram atendidos
      document.getElementById("m3").innerHTML="<font color='green'>Ok!</font>";
      console.log(resultado);
   }else{ // requisitos não foram atendidos
      document.getElementById("m3").innerHTML="<font color='red'>Campo incorreto</font>";
   }
}
```

```html
Número de Registro:<br>
<input type="text" name="registro" onblur="validaRegistro(this.value)">
<div id="m3"></div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Ajudou muito!

Comment: Vi que é novo no site. Sabe que tem que escolher uma resposta como a favorita?

Comment: Marque ✓ na sua resposta favorita. Clique no ícone ✓ ao lado da resposta.

Comment: Pegou a resposta e sumiu, kkk +1

Comment: Num é? Por isso que eu já vejo novos usuários e já passo a fita

Comment: @wilhelmandreas marque a resposta como aceita, veja como em https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png

Comment: @dvd guarda esse link da imagem pra vc poder usar https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo A partir de uma reputação, acho que 15K, se torna "usuário confiável"... ou é 20K, não lembro